# Get function is not working , passes empty to the another page

Tags: php

Well i use this form of 
**add.php**

```
echo " <td><form action='view_ticket.php' method='get'>
        <input type='hidden' id='itemid' name='itemid' value='". $row["id"] ."'/>
         <input  type='submit' value='Buy' class='btn-link'/>
       </form></td>";
echo "</tr>";
```

And i got this 
 **view_ticket.php**

```
<?php   
session_start();
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "localhost", "localhost", 
"localhost");
if ($conn->connect_error) { 
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$id = $_GET['itemid'];
$sql = "SELECT id,username FROM tickets WHERE id = '" . $id . "'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  if  ($row['username'] = $_SESSION['username']) {

  }
  else 
    {
  header("location:/quickshops/buyer/tickets.php");
    }
    }
    }
 ?>
```

the only problem i guess that $id = $_GET['itemid']; gets out empty idk how 
I checked the source code of add.php , the ids in hidden area are real ,true, and numbers

Comment: Do you see itemid in the URL on the view_ticket.php page? With GET it should show up there.

Comment: Yes i see the id there

Comment: Try var_dump($_GET); as the very first line to see if it that variable contains anything.

Answer (score 0):

Output $_GET at each step to see where you loose it, for instance

```
echo 'About to look for id "' . htmlspecialchars($id) . '"<br>';
$result = $conn->query($sql);
echo 'Just executed SQL query<br>';
var_dump($_GET); echo '<br>';
if ($result === false) {
    echo 'SQL Query Error!<br>';
    var_dump($_GET); echo '<br>';
} else if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo $result->num_rows . ' row(s) found<br>';
    var_dump($_GET); echo '<br>'; /* do something */
} else {
    echo 'No rows round<br>';
    var_dump($_GET); echo '<br>';
}
```